# backstretch 100% div height

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-backstretch

I am using the backstretch jquery plugin with multiple divs as backgrounds (sections.) Currently I am using fixed heights but I want the divs to be 100% height of the window and the page to be scrollable. How can I accomplish this?

HTML

```
<div class="main-container"></div>
<div class="main-container2"></div>
<div class="main-container3"></div>
<div class="main-container4"></div>
```

CSS

```
.main-container {
background-image:url(../images/footballfieldblur.jpg);
height:1000px;
z-index:-100;

}
.main-container2 {
background-image:url(../images/orange3.png);
height:1000px;

}
.main-container3 {
background-image:url(../images/lightbackground.jpg);
height:1000px;

}
.main-container4 {
background-image:url(../images/diamondplatebackground.jpg);
height:1000px;
```

}
JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
$(".main-container").backstretch("images/footballfieldblur.jpg");
$(".main-container2").backstretch("images/orange3.png");
$(".main-container3").backstretch("images/lightbackground.jpg");
$(".main-container4").backstretch("images/diamondplatebackground.jpg");
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the div being 100% height, and the page scrollable? The div should take up 100% height when first displayed, but can be scrolled away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body{
  height:100%;
  overflow:scroll;
}

.main{
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This seemed to be the best solution. Thanks! When you adjust the window the background image is responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You could use in html and body:

Height:100%;

or

Min-height:100%

or use javascript:

$(".main-container").css({'height':($(document).height())+'px'});

Comment: I have tried that but the boxes get smaller and don't go 100% height of window.

Comment: putting it in the css of main-container, main-container2... ect.

Comment: Gio the javascript works well too. I guess I would have to adjust accordingly to make the background image responsive like the css solution.

Comment: Okay, any questions please check back.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/Q3HWT/

```
<div class="main-container column"></div>
<div class="main-container2 column"></div>
<div class="main-container3 column"></div>
<div class="main-container4 column"></div>

html, body {position:relative; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.column {position:absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add following to CSS style section :

```
 <style>
      * { margin : 0 ;  padding : 0 ; }
 </style>
```

Hope will be helpful.